# A question regarding positive semidefinite matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $S=(S_{ij})$ is an $n\times n$ symmetric, positive semidefinite matrix with zero row and coloumn sums. Let $u_1,\ldots , u_n$ be $n$ arbitrary vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$, where $n>d$. Now suppose $$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n S_{ij}u_i^tu_j=0.$$ Then I would like to show that $\sum_{j=1}^nS_{ij}u_j=0$ for all $i$.

The above was stated without proof in the book (page 242) Graphs and Geometry by Lovasz. I suspect the proof is easy but I am unable to see it. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of matrices, the statement in question simply says that if $S$ is positive semidefinite and $\operatorname{tr}(USU^T)=0$, then $US=0$. This is because
$$
\operatorname{tr}(USU^T)=0
\Rightarrow \|US^{1/2}\|_F^2=0
\Rightarrow US^{1/2}=0
\Rightarrow US=US^{1/2}S^{1/2}=0.
$$
This has nothing to do with the row/column sums of $S$.